# OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Vertex Buffer: Out of memory

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to broadcast multiple tf frames of various joints obtained via camera. If the broadcaster frames exceed 10, i am receiving the following error from RViz.
I am followed the standard ROS tf python tutorials.

```
rviz
[ INFO] [1611363022.152502881]: rviz version 1.13.13
[ INFO] [1611363022.152561384]: compiled against Qt version 5.9.5
[ INFO] [1611363022.152580144]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1611363022.160021717]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
[ INFO] [1611363022.679843865]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1611363022.679917545]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).
[ WARN] [1611363050.130722161]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Vertex Buffer: Out of memory in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::lock at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 124)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Vertex Buffer: Out of memory in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::lock at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 124)
^C^C^C^C^C^CAborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370111/ogre-exception(7:internalerrorexception):-vertex-buffer:-out-of-memory/) by [Akr2712](https://answers.ros.org/users/56740/akr2712/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-01-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-23**:\

> ```
> [ INFO] [1611363022.160021717]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
> ```

that doesn't look like something I'd expect.

Are you doing this on purpose?

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2021-01-23**:
Even when I launch RViz, I get the same openGL version 0 issue. I did a little bit of digging and found this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/191680/opengl-error-when-run-rviz/)! maybe it's just that certain hardware cannot accelerate the graphics?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-24**:
What OS are you using? Are you running this in a Virtual Machine, or on Windows 10 WSL perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the solution in this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/191680/opengl-error-when-run-rviz/), this solution will not be working for everyone as mentioned in that link. But give it a try though and let me know ! This might accelerate your hardware!

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2021-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-24**:\

> This might accelerate your hardware!

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` completely disables acceleration / use of hw, as it forces *software rendering*.

This is at best a work-around.